# How to round decimal in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, concurrency

I have a (large ~ 1million) Scala Spark DataFrame with the following data:

```
id,score
1,0.956
2,0.977
3,0.855
4,0.866
...
```

How do I discretise/round the scores to the nearest 0.05 decimal place?

Expected result:

```
id,score
1,0.95
2,1.00
3,0.85
4,0.85
...
```

Would like to avoid using UDF to maximise performance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it using spark built in functions like so

```
dataframe.withColumn("rounded_score", round(col("score") * 100 / 5) * 5 / 100)
```

1. Multiply it so that the precision you want is a whole number.
2. Then divide that number by 5, and round.
3. Now the number is divisable by 5, so multiply it by 5 to get back the entire number
4. Divide by 100 to get the precision correct again.

result

```
+---+-----+-------------+
| id|score|rounded_score|
+---+-----+-------------+
|  1|0.956|         0.95|
|  2|0.977|          1.0|
|  3|0.855|         0.85|
|  4|0.866|         0.85|
+---+-----+-------------+
```

Answer (score 18):

The answer can be simplifier:

```
dataframe.withColumn("rounded_score", round(col("score"), 2))
```

there is a method

```
def round(e: Column, scale: Int)
```

> Round the value of `e` to `scale` decimal places with HALF_UP round mode

Comment: I think that doesn't really answer the question, as it seems the solution should round to the nearest `0.05`.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify your schema when convert into dataframe ,

Example :

DecimalType(10, 2) for the column in your customSchema when loading data.

```
id,score
1,0.956
2,0.977
3,0.855
4,0.866
...



import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val mySchema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("id", IntegerType, true),
   StructField("score", DecimalType(10, 2), true)
))

spark.read.format("csv").schema(mySchema).
  option("header", "true").option("nullvalue", "?").
  load("/path/to/csvfile").show
```